# Generating VS2010 solution with CMake invalidates include directories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, cmake

I'm trying to generate a VS2010 solution for ASEPRITE (http://code.google.com/p/aseprite/) but when I follow the instructions in INSTALL.TXT it seems all the include directories get messed up and nothing will include properly.

Is this an issue with ASE or am I just doing it wrong?

(BTW I understand that to answer this question you would need to take a look at the ASE code and that may be a lot to ask but if someone has time to do that then I would appreciate it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an error in the code itself, which has now been fixed.